# Java recursion in JVM for indexing

Tags: java

I have this project from uni that i am dealing with Binary(Search) Trees
The object of a class creates a Tree(left) Label(A Item) Tree(Right)
here is the constructor so you can understand what i am dealing with

```
  public NonEmptyTree(Tree<A> left,A label,Tree<A> right)
{
    this.left=left;
    treeSize = 1;
    this.label=label;
    this.right=right;
    assert left!=null && right!=null && label!=null;
    //parent is set elsewhere
}
```

The task is to find those labels within the JVM based on their index so here is my logic

```
  public A get(int index){
    A node = null;
    if(index < treeSize || index >= 0 ){
        if(this.size() == index){
           node = (A) label;
        }
        else if( node == null){
             int leftSide = this.getForest(left);
            int rightSide = this.getForest(right) + this.getForest(left);
            if(index <= leftSide || index == 0) {
                left.get(index);

            }
            else if(index < leftSide + rightSide && index > leftSide + 1){
                right.get(index);
            }
        }
    }
    return node;  
}
```

this method also uses the method below to compute the sizes of left and right subtrees and determine which Tree i should go down the path to look for the label

```
public int getForest(Tree<A> tree){
    if(left.size() > 0 && right.size() > 0){
        treeSize = this.size();
        this.getForest(tree);
    }else if(left.size() == 0){
        treeSize = 0;
    }
    else{
        this.treeSize = 1;
    }
    return treeSize;
}
```

when i go into testing i have  LTree<"ali"> <"hi"> RTree<"do-nothing">(its empty)

so when i run the debugger method with this logic everything runs smoothly it goes into the LTree and assign the label to node but on the line `return node;`  it goes back to `left.get(index)` and returns "hi" or null

So am i missing something that i don't know of from the recursion strategy?

PS. even though we have an iterator method(which i originally had it like that) the module is about algorithms and efficiency so iterator will lose me marks even it works

Answer (score 0):

your problem is in the return value. Your recursive function must be like this:

```
public A get(int index){
    A node = null;
    if(index < treeSize || index >= 0 ){
        if(this.size() == index){
          return node = (A) label;
        }
        else if( node == null){
             int leftSide = this.getForest(left);
            int rightSide = this.getForest(right) + this.getForest(left);
            if(index <= leftSide || index == 0) {
                return left.get(index);

            }
            else if(index < leftSide + rightSide && index > leftSide + 1){
               return right.get(index);
            }
        }
    }
    return node;  
}
```

or you can just assign the value to node like this:

```
public A get(int index){
    A node = null;
    if(index < treeSize || index >= 0 ){
        if(this.size() == index){
           node = (A) label;
        }
        else if( node == null){
             int leftSide = this.getForest(left);
            int rightSide = this.getForest(right) + this.getForest(left);
            if(index <= leftSide || index == 0) {
               node = left.get(index);

            }
            else if(index < leftSide + rightSide && index > leftSide + 1){
               node = right.get(index);
            }
        }
    }
    return node;  
}
```

Comment: thanks it worked now i have to fix the code for the right side...also i had to include if(index == left.size())